# Selecionar radio ao clicar em um button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quero que quando a pessoa clicar no *botão 1*, automaticamente o *radio 2* seja selecionado, evitando assim que o usuário faça dois cliques.

Como posso fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Acontecerá a mesma coisa também quando selecionar outro meio de pagamento.

[Link da página:](https://wholl.com.br/homolog/carrinho/)

---

Tentei utilizar esse exemplo do rapaz acima, mas checked está dando null!!!

Aonde estou errando?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">// true = selecionar ~ false = deselecionar

function um(){
document.getElementById('payment_method_iugu-credit-card').checked = true;
document.getElementById('payment_method_iugu-bank-slip').checked = false;
document.getElementById('payment_method_wc_ticket_installments').checked = false;
document.getElementById('payment_method_pagseguro').checked = false;
}
function dois(){
document.getElementById('payment_method_iugu-credit-card').checked = false;
document.getElementById('payment_method_iugu-bank-slip').checked = true;
document.getElementById('payment_method_wc_ticket_installments').checked = false;
document.getElementById('payment_method_pagseguro').checked = false;
}
function tres(){
document.getElementById('payment_method_iugu-credit-card').checked = false;
document.getElementById('payment_method_iugu-bank-slip').checked = false;
document.getElementById('payment_method_wc_ticket_installments').checked = true;
document.getElementById('payment_method_pagseguro').checked = false;
}

function quatro(){
document.getElementById('payment_method_iugu-credit-card').checked = false;
document.getElementById('payment_method_iugu-bank-slip').checked = false;
document.getElementById('payment_method_wc_ticket_installments').checked = false;
document.getElementById('payment_method_pagseguro').checked = true;
}</script>
```

```html
<div class="textopagamento"><h3>Pagamento</h3></div>
  <ul class="abapagamento nav nav-tabs">
 <li ><a id="bot-um" onclick="um()" href="#divhideiugu-credit-card">Cartão S/ Juros</a></li>
 <li ><a id="bot-dois" onclick="dois()" href="#divhideiugu-bank-slip">Boleto à Vista </a></li>
 <li ><a id="bot-tres" onclick="tres()" href="#divhidewc_ticket_installments">Boleto Parcelado </a></li>
 <li ><a id="bot-quatro" onclick="quatro()" href="#divhidepagseguro">Pag Seguro</a></li>
     
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Seria importante colocar na pergunta o HTML dos botões e dos radios para que possamos saber a estrutura e vincular um botão a cada radio.

Comment: Postei o link da página pois o código HTML é muito extenso.

Comment: @MatheusRodrigues Se o código original é muito extenso, vc pode reduzi-lo para um **[mcve]** <== clique neste link, tem ótimas dicas para reduzir o código para um equivalente que reproduza o mesmo comportamento e/ou problema do seu código original. Isso é importante porque toda a informação relevante deve estar na pergunta. Links devem ser apenas para complemento. Se o link estiver fora do ar, por exemplo, ainda sim a pergunta continuará com todas as informações. Veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5489/112052).

Answer (score 0):

**Matheus existem diversas formas de se fazer isto:**

> Se quiser uma coisa mais dinâmica no exemplo abaixo eu marco o radio e adiciono o respectivo nome do botão clicado.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    var texto = $(this).text();
    $("#radio").prop("checked", true);
    $("span").html(texto);
  })
})
```

```css
button{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: purple;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="pag-seguro">Pag Seguro</button>
<button>Cartão sem juros</button>
<button>Boleto parcelado</button>

<br><br>

<input type="radio" id="radio"><span></span>
```

> Agora o que estava procurando era só marcar o **check** pode fazer assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button:eq(0)").on("click", function() {
    $("input:eq(0)").prop("checked", true);
  })
  $("button:eq(1)").on("click", function() {
    $("input:eq(1)").prop("checked", true);
  })
  $("button:eq(2)").on("click", function() {
    $("input:eq(2)").prop("checked", true);
  })
})
```

```css
button{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: purple;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Pag Seguro</button>
<button>Cartão sem juros</button>
<button>Boleto parcelado</button>

<br><br>

<input type="radio" id="pag">Pag Seguro
<input type="radio" id="car">Cartão sem juros
<input type="radio" id="bol">Boleto parcelado
```